# Intel OpenCL SDK for Windows XP?

Tags: opencl

I want to know if there is any version of Intel's opencl implementation for windows XP?I have searched quite a lot about it and didnt find anything .But thought i'd confirm here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. They list only Vista and Windows 7. I doubt XP will be supported.

[AMD](http://developer.amd.com/gpu/AMDAPPSDK/downloads/Pages/default.aspx) support XP at present, if what you really want is OpenCL for CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Found on the Internet:

[Making OpenCL features available - Wings 3D](http://www.wings3d.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=174)

> For old Intel processors (like P4) or on-board GPU (like Intel G33/31): ATI Stream SDK 2.3 is the last version that supports Windows XP SP3